# I can't figure out how to put together an API with a key in the get request

Tags: python, api-key

I'm really new to programming, but I'm trying to put together my first API. It's going to a Fortnite tracker, and their documentation is nonexistent. It wants me to put in an API key in the header, but how am I supposed to put a header in the get request? Here's what I'm calling:

```
fnStats = requests.get('https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/{platform}/{account}', headers = {'key': myPersonalKey'})
```

Here's what it returns, with my account name and platform plugged in correctly:

```
{"message":"No API key found in request"}
```

Is there an implied way to send the API key?

EDIT: Here is their 'documentation' page: https://fortnitetracker.com/site-api

Answer (score 1):

I think first you need to create a API key suing your credentials through their website. Then pass on that key in GET request.

```
In header your "key" should be the keyname "value" should be actual value.
headers = {
  'key_name': 'value'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside the `.get()` call, `{'key': 'myPersonalKey'}` is a placeholder. You need to replace the 'myPersonalKey' string *with your own actual personal API key*, which is something the doc tells you you have to get:

> *"To make use of our APIs we require you to use an API Key. To use the API key you need to pass it along as a header with your requests. [Manage or Create API Keys](https://tracker.gg/developers/apps)"*

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I'm aware of my placeholder as the API key should be private. Also, I created an API key but I don't know how to pass it through the .get() function

Comment: Replace the string 'myPersonalKey' with your actual key **inside the `.get()` call**. If you say that still fails after you replace it, recheck your code, or contact that API issuer. (For security reasons, never post your own actual API key publicly here on SO or elsewhere)